# Set origin and rotation on a path with SVG's animateMotion

Tags: svg, animation

I'd like to apply a rotation on a path animated with SVG's animateMotion tag. [Here's](https://jsfiddle.net/fillotassi/by3Lxf0h/6/) where I'm stuck at, my aim was to repeat the animated circle on the other three lines.

It seems that *transform-origin:50%;transform: rotate(240deg);* doesn't apply on the path tag that the motion follows.

Comment: This is *probably* a better fit for StackOverflow.com

Comment: In sequence or at the same time?